# Bars not aligning with X-axis tick and first bar cut-off in Bokeh plot

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook, bar-chart, bokeh

I went through the posts that auto-populated based on my question title but couldn't find anything quite aligned to my oddball result.

I'm feeding in a CSV file of a packet capture and collecting the protocols, summing the lengths of each protocol per protocol individually, then dividing by the protocol totals to get the average packet size per protocol.

Using my display commands, I'm able to confirm that the columns protocol and bytes have the same size (There are 18 protocols and 18 averages of byte sizes). I was also able to confirm that the graph is drawing correctly aside from two things that could possibly be looked at as one problem.

1. The first bar for "DNS" starts early and is half cut-off
2. The bars are not aligned over the x-axis ticks

I tried to replicate the issue using the simple Bokeh fruit example in their documentation, but it plotted normally, but that was simply creating a dummy array with x and y.

[Off-Center Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wd5jN.png)

Here is the code, but bear in mind that the CSV file is not attached and due to IP addresses, I have to refrain from sharing that, but any advice or suggestions if anyone has seen this would be greatly appreciated.

Also, here is the result of [temp.head()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/28baE.png).

```
# Here is the myriad of declarations that helps this program work

import pandas as pd
import math as m
import ipympl
import ipywidgets
import numpy as np

# Bokeh libraries and modules (I am aware not all of these are required, just
# occasionally trying a few fun features, though let me know if this could be
# the problem)

from bokeh.io import  show, reset_output, output_notebook, export_png
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file
from bokeh.models import Range1d, FactorRange, ColumnDataSource, LabelSet, HoverTool
from bokeh.models import ColorBar, LogColorMapper, LogTicker
from bokeh.layouts import gridplot, row, column
from bokeh.transform import factor_cmap, linear_cmap
from bokeh.models.annotations import Label
from bokeh.models.tools import HoverTool
from bokeh.palettes import Spectral6, Category20, viridis, turbo, linear_palette

# Set up plots to stay inside the notebook
# Remove this when you want to bring up a separate window display

output_notebook()

# Set up Bokeh visualtization toolset  

TOOLS = "pan,wheel_zoom,box_zoom,reset,save"

data_r = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\xxx.csv')
data_s = data_r.groupby('Protocol').Length.sum()
data_p = data_r.groupby('Protocol').Source.count()
data_a_p = data_s / data_p
data_a_p_df = data_a_p.to_frame()

temp = data_a_p_df.reset_index()
temp.columns = ['Protocol', 'bytes']

# Setting up the ColumnDataSource
cds = ColumnDataSource(temp)

p = figure(x_range=cds.data['Protocol'],
           plot_height=300,
           plot_width=800, 
           title="Average Packet Size by Protocol",
           y_axis_label='Size in Bytes',
           tools=TOOLS)

p.vbar(range(len(cds.data['Protocol'])), 
       width=.8,
       top=cds.data['bytes'],
       line_color='black',
       fill_color=turbo(len(cds.data['Protocol'])),
       fill_alpha=.5)

# To help the labels fit nicely, rotate the x-axis labels 45 degrees
p.xaxis.major_label_orientation = 45

# Display the graph
show(p)
display (len(cds.data['Protocol'])) # Results in 18
display (len(cds.data['bytes'])) # Results in 18
```

**Edit:** To make a functioning example showing the error, here is updated code that uses a dummy data frame:

```
# Here is the myriad of declarations that helps this program work
# Note I added prettytable to make the dummy csv file

import pandas as pd
import math as m
import ipympl
import ipywidgets
import numpy as np

# Bokeh libraries and modules (I am aware not all of these are required, just
# occasionally trying a few fun features, though let me know if this could be
# the problem)

from bokeh.io import  show, reset_output, output_notebook, export_png
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file
from bokeh.models import Range1d, FactorRange, ColumnDataSource, LabelSet, HoverTool
from bokeh.models import ColorBar, LogColorMapper, LogTicker
from bokeh.layouts import gridplot, row, column
from bokeh.transform import factor_cmap, linear_cmap
from bokeh.models.annotations import Label
from bokeh.models.tools import HoverTool
from bokeh.palettes import Spectral6, Category20, viridis, turbo, linear_palette

# Set up plots to stay inside the notebook
# Remove this when you want to bring up a separate window display

output_notebook()

# Set up Bokeh visualtization toolset  

TOOLS = "pan,wheel_zoom,box_zoom,reset,save"

# For this example I created a dummy dataframe for the data

data_r = pd.DataFrame({
   'Protocol': ['DNS','DNS', 'TCP', 'ICMPv6', 'TCP', 'TCP',
                 'HTTP', 'HTTP', 'TCP', 'TCP', 'TCP', 'TCP',
                 'TCP', 'ICMPv6', 'TCP', 'TCP', 'TCP', 
                 'ICMPv6', 'ICMPv6', 'AJP13', 'AJP13'],
   'Length': [96, 154, 66, 110, 171, 171, 208, 209, 56, 56,
            56, 56, 66, 110, 54, 55, 56, 110, 110, 171, 171]
})

data_s = data_r.groupby('Protocol').Length.sum()
data_p = data_r.groupby('Protocol').Protocol.count()
data_a_p = data_s / data_p
data_a_p_df = data_a_p.to_frame()

temp = data_a_p_df.reset_index()
temp.columns = ['Protocol', 'bytes']

# Setting up the ColumnDataSource
cds = ColumnDataSource(temp)

p = figure(x_range=cds.data['Protocol'],
           plot_height=300,
           plot_width=800, 
           title="Average Packet Size by Protocol",
           y_axis_label='Size in Bytes',
           tools=TOOLS)

p.vbar(range(len(cds.data['Protocol'])), 
       width=.8,
       top=cds.data['bytes'],
       line_color='black',
       fill_color=turbo(len(cds.data['Protocol'])),
       fill_alpha=.5)

# To help the labels fit nicely, rotate the x-axis labels 45 degrees
p.xaxis.major_label_orientation = 45

# Display the graph
show(p)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, when you provide a code that relies on some data, do provide that data as well. Not as a picture of `temp.head()`, but as something that can be copied. Ideally, just include some toy data within the code itself.

As to your question - just don't use `range(len(...))` in `p.vbar`. Simply provide `cds.data['Protocol']` as the first argument.

Comment: Eugene, I updated the code to have a dummy data frame that shows the error others may be running into, it won't look the same but I do want to help the community when I can. 

You are correct however and that was my issue. If I'm setting the range to be based off of the len, what causes it to move what is essentially -0.5 on the x-axis? Many thanks for your assistance and guidance. Your answer was useful, though apparently I am too much of a SO lurker noob to actually click the "this answer is useful" up arrow

Comment: By using categorical values, you're asking Bokeh to compute the synthetic coordinates for you. By using numerical values, you're telling Bokeh that you're providing the synthetic coordinates yourself. And it would require some particular computation based on the knowledge of the internals of Bokeh. Why `-0.5` in particular - no particular reason, I think. Probably it just happened because the distance of `1` between neighbor categories seemed reasonable.